# Imported struct to be used as anonymous field

Tags: go

So I'm trying to write a few Go files such that there is a public facing package and an internal package.

In the public facing package, there is a struct that is nearly identical (missing one field) to an internal struct.

I thought of using an anonymous field in the internal struct, but it doesn't seem to play nicely.

---

Example:

public/public.go:

```
package public

type PublicStruct struct {
    Field1 bool `json:"fetchStats"`
}
```

data/data.go

```
package data

import publicData "public"

type InternalStruct struct {
    publicData.PublicStruct
    Field2 bool `json:"includeHidden:`
}
```

filter/filter.go:

```
package filter

import "data"

func test() {
    tmp := data.InternalStruct{Field1: true, Field2: false}
}
```

main.go:

```
package main

import "filter"
import "data"

func main() {
    var tmp data.InternalStruct
    tmp.Field1 = true
    tmp.Field2 = true
    filter.Test()
}
```

---

Expected: no issues

Result: `filter/filter.go:6: unknown data.InternalStruct field 'Field1' in struct literal`

---

Why does this not work and what should I do to make it work (I'm currently using the duplicate parameters in both structs approach)?

---

PS: I don't know how to test this in go playground since it involves multiple files.

Comment: Don't use `.` imports, it's considered bad practice outside of testing. Also note that `internal` is a restricted import path and prevent outside package from importing it (which may be intended in your case)

Comment: I get that `import . ` is bad practice, but it was the only way that I know of to get the anonymous struct to work as closely as possible.

I used `import public` before and the anonymous field was `public.PublicStruct`, but that didn't work either

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to, importing via "." doesn't change the semantics of struct embedding.

Comment: it changes the referencing so using PublicStruct would appear the same in internal as it would in public. I'm pretty sure that it's just namespace-ing, but I hoped that when something imported internal and used InternalStruct, Field1 could be accessed without any issue.

Comment: The name of the embedded struct is irrelevant, and the selector will resolve Field1 the same regardless. I think you may misunderstand how embedding works. Please show a reproducible example, with the expected outcome, and without using the "." import or the reserved "internal" package.

Comment: Sorry about the inconvenience. I was trying to remove unnecessary parts. I updated the example. Hopefully what I'm trying to achieve is more visible now.

Comment: That works as expected (and marshals to `{"fetchStats":false,"includeHidden":false}` after the typo fix), so I have a feeling you're not importing what you think you are. Check your files, and GOPATH structure, etc.

Comment: I updated the post to contain the folder and file names that I used inside the src folder. I also included my main.go file. Accessing Field1 and Field2 in a variable does not have any issues, but if I use filter.Test(), I get unknown field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `field1` isn't being exported by the public package as it's name is lower cased. If it were instead `Field1` then you could access it inside the internal package like `MyInternalStructInstance.Field1`

EDIT - Addresses OP's update;

The syntax you're using for initilization in your main is just wrong. It should be:

```
tmp := InternalStruct{PublicStruct: PublicStruct{Field1: true}, Field2: false}
```

It has nothing to do with the packages or imported vs exported. It can easily be tested on the playground, a complete example is here; https://play.golang.org/p/tbCqFeNStd

Comment: That was a typo. Field1 should actually be capitalized.

Comment: @EltonYang I updated with the solution to the problem you're currently facing.

Comment: That makes sense, but I was hoping that there would be a way to pass through PublicStruct and being able to reference Field1 as though it were a part of InternalStruct, similarly to how inheritance works for other languages. Seeing as how that isn't possible, I'll mark your answer as correct. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @EltonYang the language feature you're using here is called embedding and it does work like that for access, just not for initilization. In this case you have to be explicit, like declare the embedded type before you can declare it's fields. After that statement you can do `tmp.Field1` and you won't get any errors, it will be the same as doing `tmp.PublicStruct.Field1` but that's really the only thing embedding gives you. It's more equivalent to composition than inheritance though it provides some useful aspects of both.